# How can I get localized year only in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript

I know I can use `new Date().toLocaleDateString('locale-key-here')` to get the whole date.

But I only want the localized year, for example 2023 in `en` equals to `1444` in `ar`, and 1401 in `fa` locales.

How can I get that? I don't see `toLocaleYear()` or something similar.

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Intl/Locale/calendar

Comment: Can you define what you mean by localized? 1999 is 1999 in both Russia and USA.
Do you want to get years from one timestamp for different non-gregorian calendars?

Comment: @zerdox, 2023 in `en` equals to 1444 in `ar` and 1401 in `fa`. Numbers are different.

Comment: @AliRadan I've added your comment above to your question, please edit the question to contain the exact locale you want to get the year from.

Answer (score 3):

You could use the [`year` option](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Intl/DateTimeFormat/DateTimeFormat#year) with [`toLocaleDateString`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/toLocaleDateString) to get a a language-sensitive representation of the year :

```js
console.log(new Date().toLocaleDateString("fr-FR", {year: "numeric"}));
console.log(new Date().toLocaleDateString("fr-FR", {year: "2-digit"}));
console.log(new Date().toLocaleDateString("ar-EG", {year: "numeric"}));
console.log(new Date().toLocaleDateString("ar-EG", {year: "2-digit"}));
// Using a non-Gregrorian calendar, in this case Islamic:
console.log(new Date().toLocaleDateString("ar-MA-u-ca-islamic", {year: "numeric"}));
console.log(new Date().toLocaleDateString("ar-MA-u-ca-islamic", {year: "2-digit"}));
```

The optional `options` argument to `toLocaleDateString` is used internally by `toLocaleDateString` as the `options` argument of [`Intl.DateTimeFormat()` constructor](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Intl/DateTimeFormat/DateTimeFormat); the options are described there.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `Intl` package, so you can show the year from different calendars, Bellow examples of some calendars:

```js
var date = new Date();
ops = {year: "numeric"};

// Default calendar
console.log(new Intl.DateTimeFormat('en-GB', ops).format(new Date()));

// Islamic calendar
console.log(new Intl.DateTimeFormat('en-GB-u-ca-islamic', ops).format(new Date()));

// Japanese Imperial calendar
console.log(new Intl.DateTimeFormat('en-GB-u-ca-japanese', ops).format(new Date()));

// Ethiopic calendar
console.log(new Intl.DateTimeFormat('en-GB-u-ca-ethiopic', ops).format(new Date()));

// Traditional Hebrew calendar
console.log(new Intl.DateTimeFormat('en-GB-u-ca-hebrew', ops).format(new Date()));

// Indian calendar
console.log(new Intl.DateTimeFormat('en-GB-u-ca-indian', ops).format(new Date()));
```

Answer (score 1):

Note: [Tom's subsequent answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75602736/157247) usefully shows a shorter way to get this information.

Since you've asked for something locale-specific, I'll point you to the [`Intl.DateTimeFormat`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Intl/DateTimeFormat) class.

For instance, you can use `formatToParts` and get the year from it:

```js
const formatter = new Intl.DateTimeFormat();
const parts = formatter.formatToParts(new Date());
const year = parts.find(({type}) => type === "year").value;
console.log(year);
```

I can't find a reference saying so, but presumably **if** the default locale uses a different calendar than the Gregorian one, you'll get the locale's year. Here's an example where I force it to use a Buddhist calendar and another where I force it to use an Islamic calendar (see [this MDN page](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Intl/Locale/calendar) for how calendar suffixes are added to locale strings):

```js
function example(locale) {
    const formatter = new Intl.DateTimeFormat(locale);
    const parts = formatter.formatToParts(new Date());
    const year = parts.find(({type}) => type === "year").value;
    console.log(`Locale ${locale ?? "(default)"}: ${year}`);
}

example();
example("zh-CN-u-ca-buddhist")
example("ar-MA-u-ca-islamic")
```

Comment: As I know js currently doesn't know about non-gregorian calendars, so your answer doesn't differ from `Date().getFullYear()`

Comment: @zerdox - It does. It remains open to the fact that the year may vary by locale, rather than being closed to it and making an assumption.